# Connecting to Internal MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, security

I have a Node.JS Express API App that's hosted on Heroku in the cloud. I'd like to query a MySQL DB.

The problem is that this DB is hosted on a secure LAN with proprietary info. We don't want to expose this DB to the public. What's the desired pattern for things like this?

I have a static proxy IP that I was thinking of maybe whitelisting in MySQL Server if possible. I think introducing another layer like VPN or SSH isn't going to work.

Comment: Can you just firewall-allow the IP of your application server?

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 1):

*I have a static proxy IP that I was thinking of maybe whitelisting in MySQL Server if possible*

MySQL does allow whitelisting of IPs. It is possible.

However, you can create an SSH tunnel from the local system to the server. The SSH tunnel can give you an encrypted SSH connection. And instead of using an SSH based on password, the better method is to use a key based encryption

What you need to do is to generate a public authentication key and append it to the remote hosts ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. And preferably, disable password based authentication and only permit key based ssh connections.

If you need some steps on how to achieve this, I can list down too.

Comment: Mm..but don't you think tunneling through SSH (from Node Express) is a bit awkward? It's introducing another layer that could slow down client requests, thoughts?

Comment: SSH tunneling is indeed on the slower side. I recommended it from a security perspective as the OP didnt mention about connection response times. If security and response time are factors, then I suggest stunnel and/or openVPN. open VPN has a better edge owing to underlying UDP usage.